# A real life system that faces and solves the dining philosophers problem

Tags: operating-systems, concurrency, deadlocks

I'm looking for an application of the dining philosophers problem. Is there some real life system that faces the concurrency problem of "the dining philosophers problem" and implements a solution? I've been searching for over an hour.

It would be even better if the implemented solution is [Tanenbaum's solution described here](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/classes/p415-sjoh/hw/project/dining-philosophers/index.htm).

Answer (score 3):

The dining philosopher's problem is a worst case scenario used to illustrate issues in algorithms. It's a test case. You probably won't find a static one-to-one mapping between it and a real world case.

However, similar situations can occur dynamically. If at any point the graph of actors waiting for resources forms a cycle, you are stuck in a deadlock. Most of the time this happens with n = 2 actors, but sometimes you can get more complicated deadlocks.